# Error: TargetInvocationException in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I have installed a fresh (and clean) Sitecore 5.3.1 on a Windows 2003 server. Setup the DB (SQL) and given Network service full access to both data, databases and website folder.

When i enter the backend, i can login, view the menu etc., but almost all the time, whenever i try to do something, like installing a package, it just freezes up, and comes with and error (cannot be null for instance).
When i look in the eventviewer on the server i see this;

```
Exception type: TargetInvocationException 
Exception message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 1 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MethodCommandProcessor.Invoke(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Resume()
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.DoStart(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MethodCommand.Execute(CommandContext context)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Dispatch(String command)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent()
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I have no clue what it is i am missing?

Comment: the package you are trying to install... are you sure it is compatible?

Comment: Yep. But it is not just the package install that fails. When i try to Rebuild the linkdatabase with Sitecore's own built-in tool, it also fails etc.

Comment: did you get any errors/warnings at the time of installation? I think this could be due to some compatibility between sitecore and environment. Also, why not installing sitecore 6.5?

Comment: I unstalled from a zip file, not via the installer. No errors or problems. 5.3 is required for this particular project.

Comment: can you try using the installer instead? I have a feeling that it would throw some error related to setup. Also, what browser are you using with the client?

Comment: Tried the installer - same thing. No errors during install. I am using IE9.

Comment: I have "fixed" the problem for now, by installing it on my local windows 7 dev machine instead - here it works without any issues. Thx for the time :)

Comment: yeah there is something up with that environment that sitecore did not like. wish it throw an error to help us understand. but I am glad you figured it out.